# This webpage has a redirect loop asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies, routes

I have a startup class with following code

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType="ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/auth/login")
            });
        }
    }
```

When I run my project showing me

> The webpage at
>   /auth/login?ReturnUrl=%2Fauth%2Flogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Fauth%252Flogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Fauth%25252Flogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252Fauth%2525252Flogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252Fauth%252525252Flogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252Fauth%25252525252Flogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252Fauth%2525252525252Flogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252Fauth%252525252525252Flogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252Fauth%25252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252Fauth%2525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252Fauth%252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252Fauth%25252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252Fauth%2525252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252Fauth%252525252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252Fauth%25252525252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252Fauth%2525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252Fauth%252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252Fauth%25252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Fauth%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Fauth%252525252525252525252525252525252525252Flogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
>   has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this
>   site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it
>   is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your
>   computer.

I cleared my cookie but still unchanged.

Comment: I've got the same issue! I tried Chrome, IE and FF, all showed the same error.

Comment: You have not shown the relevant code. Best guess is that you login method is not decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]` so you creating and endless loop

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @StephenMuecke this is from a 
endless redirect loop.

If the page you are trying to land need authentication to view, by either having `[Authorize]` 
on the controller class or :

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController:Controller
{
```

or at the controller ActionResult:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index
```

This will redirect the user to the login page.

If this does not allow anonymous authenitcation, it is immpossible for a user to land on the page 
without being logged in.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Login(string message, string returnUrl)
{
```

Hence the app keeps redirecting the user to the login page continously until there is 
some type of overflow.

You need to use this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string message, string returnUrl)
{
```

> ReturnUrl=%2Fauth%2Flogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252Fauth%252Flogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252Fauth%

The return url requires authentication, so login, which requires authentication.. and so on.

This same prinicple works throughout your entire project.